# the header() location is not working on the server but it works in the localhost

Tags: php

This is my code....
Its query is working but problem in the header().......
plz help..........

```
$d=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin where ad_email='{$_POST['email']}'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_object($d);
    $fid=$row->ad_email;
    $fpass=$row->password;
    if($fid==$_POST['email'] && $fpass==$_POST['password'])
      {
       $_SESSION['admin']=$_POST['email'];
       header("location: http://www.myhostexampl.co.in/alprofile.php");
       exit();
      }
     else
      {
       echo 'invalid id or pass';
      }
```

Comment: try to use ob_start() function at the beginning of the page.

Comment: no use.......already done that......

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. 
Instead of using 
`header('location:your_url_to_redirect');` 
try with 
`header('Location:your_url_to_redirect');`

still if it will not work then please try with below code:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "your_url_to_redirect";</script>';
```

Comment: Sorry to say but i also use this script tag.....it redirected but the session is not working............

Comment: Have you start the session on both pages i.e the page from your redirecting and the page on which you have redirected. On both these pages session_start() will be the first line so you can access the session data.

Comment: Can you please show entire your code from both pages. and As per your question it is related to not redirecting to the different page not related to the session. :)

Comment: please give me your email id

Comment: I think it is not allowed to send the email id on this site. You have to ask here whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

`Location:` must start with uppercase **L** and there **must be a space after :** 
It should be like

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```